# Make Images Overlap in Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I wanted the images to overlap if images is more than 1. But only show 3 images, then add a circular shape with a plus and the number of images left. My problem is how do I overlap them the correct way?

**Something like this**

[image]

Codesandbox: [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-styled-components-tutorial-forked-70li3z?file=/src/App.js)

```
    <div className="resellers">
      {images.slice(0, 2).map((image, i) => (
        <span className="reseller" key={i}>
          <img src={image} alt="" />{" "}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
    {images.length > 2 && (
      <div className="plus">
        <span> + {images.length - 2} </span>
      </div>
    )}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Render all the reseller ***and*** the plus `div` elements within the `resellers` container. You'll want to render the avatars in reverse order so that they can correctly "overlay" the avatar to the right.

### Code

```
<Resellers>
  {!!images.slice(2).length && (
    <ResellerPlus>
      <span>+ {images.slice(2).length}</span>
    </ResellerPlus>
  )}
  {images
    .slice(0, 2)
    .reverse()
    .map((image, i) => (
      <Reseller key={i}>
        <img src={image} alt="reseller" />
      </Reseller>
    ))}
</Resellers>
```

### Styled Components

```
const Resellers = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse; // <-- un-reverse avatars
`;
```

Collect all the common CSS into the "reseller" div.

```
const Reseller = styled.div`
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
  border: 4px solid #fff;      // <-- white space around
  border-radius: 50%;          // <-- circle divs
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: Nunito-Bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;            // <-- hide edges of images
  text-align: center;          // <-- center text
  width: 40px;

  :not(:first-child) {
    margin-right: -0.5rem;     // <-- apply overlap
  }

  img {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
`;

const ResellerPlus = styled(Reseller)`
  font-family: Nunito-SemiBold;

  span {
    width: 100%;               // <-- help center text
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit make-images-overlap-in-styled-components]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like this to the `.reseller` class should get the basic effect.

```
.reseller {
   margin-right: -15px;
   border-radius: 100%;
   border: solid white 3px;
}
```

If you want to stack them left in front of right, you can use `z-index` or `flex-direction` to change the order they are rendered at.

Comment: Can you fork my codesandbox? Seems circles bit distorted